# Can't compile in x86 release wxWidgets

Tags: visual-studio, wxwidgets

I have a problem with visual studio; tried to set up 
`wxWidgets` libraries in these 4 modalities:

1. Debug x64 & x86
2. Release x64 & x86

The only that doesn't work is release x86.

I have this error:

[image: Here's the error]

Answer (score 0):

An internal compiler problem like this has nothing to do with wxWidgets, you need to check your hardware (notably RAM) and maybe upgrade your compiler to the latest version, just in case it could be a bug fixed in it.

P.S. Please don't post screenshots when you could paste just the text error messages.